# Cannot connect to local MySQL server using socket (2) in Elastic beanstalk using RDS database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am creating a CI\CD for my Ruby on Rails application running in Elastic Beanstalk using code pipeline. My Code build succeeds but deployment to EBS provider fails with the below error

```
+ cd /var/app/ondeck
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb db:migrate' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20211229-11836-pzl6dq11836' as your home directory temporarily.
  + '[' false = true ']'
  + su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp
  `/home/webapp` is not a directory.
  Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20211229-11840-9hxmcz11840' as your home directory temporarily.
  rake aborted!
  Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.7/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.7/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
  (See full trace by running task with --trace) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I have

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

and could connect to External RDS MySQL Aurora database.

my Buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
    phases:
      install:
        runtime-versions:
            ruby: 2.6
        commands:
          - echo Installing Bundler...
          - gem install bundler
          - bundle install
      pre_build:
        commands:
          - echo Preparing database to run tests... 
          - bundle exec rails db:create --trace RAILS_ENV=production
      build:
        commands:
          - echo Running tests...
          - bundle exec rails test/test_helper.rb
    artifacts:
      files:
        - '**/*'
```

My database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_TEST'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB'] %>`
```

Comment: If its external database, why do you connect to local one? Set your app to connect to remote host, not local.

Comment: Ya..I could understand that but when I run my codepipeline to deploy to aws elastic beanstalk it fails with the error mentioned.

Comment: I tried with the following config in ec2 instnce still the issue exists.   [ec2-user@ip-xx.xx.xx etc]$ cat my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for a similar problem connecting to a mysql server from Rails EB SSH that might still help you. Basically, Elastic Beanstalk was not successfully using my environment's envars to run my `bundle exec rails console` command in the `eb ssh` instance access.

I solved my issue by prepending all of the required envars explicitly to any rails commands I ran from within the `eb ssh` instance access. So for example, in order to run your `su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp` command, you may have to change that to run something like the following:

`su -s /bin/bash -c 'leader_only RAILS_MASTER_KEY=xxxxxxx RAILS_ENV=production DB_HOST=xxxxxxx DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx DB_USER=xxxxxxx DB=xxxxxx AWS_REGION=xxxxxxx AWS_BUCKET=xxxxxxx bundle exec rake db:migrate' webapp`

Replace the `xxxxxxx`s above with the values from the corresponding variables in your EB > Configuration > Software tab, and you should be able to connect to the remote database that way. After that, you will be able to run migration commands, rake tasks and other database-reliant functions. I'm not familiar with CI/CD but I hope the principles of this solution are adaptable to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. But I faced the issue because of the master branch in git not updated properly.
After updating the master branch with proper application code, the CI\CD initiated as expected but got stuck in between because of env and credential file not in git.
I create a s3 bucket to store the env files and referred those file while packaging it for EBS deployment.
Hope this helps someone in future :)